# Correction factor for the standard deviation

Tags: self-study, estimation, clustered-standard-errors

I know that there is at least another page with inputs on this problem but I have some additional questions not included in them (I think) and I don't know if I should post in that thread instead of making a new one. Anyway, here's the question.

I have $X_1,X_2... X_n$ iid $Normal(\theta,\theta^2)$, $\theta>0$

The requirements is to find $c_n$ such that $c_nS_n$ is unbiased for $\theta$ where $S_n$ is the sample standard deviation.

I got $c_n$ through the following steps:

$S_n=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-m_n)^2}$ where $m_n$ is the sample mean.

$S_n=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-m_n)^2}$

$S_n=\theta\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}}\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-m_n)^2}{\theta^2}}$

$\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-m_n)^2}{\theta^2}}\sim\chi(n-1)$

So,

$E(S_n)=(\theta\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}})E(\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-m_n)^2}{\theta^2}})$

$E(S_n)=(\theta\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}})\frac{\Gamma(\frac {n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}$

Is this correct? Is looks different from the one in the link above which shows $\frac{\Gamma(\frac n2)}{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})}$.

My second question is, is the fact that this question has $X_i's$ normal with mean $\theta$ (and the variance $\theta^2$) instead of the general case of $\mu$ relevant in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution) the mean of the chi distribution with $n-1$ df is

$$E(X) = \sqrt{2} \frac{ \Gamma(n/2) }{ \Gamma( \left(n-1\right)/2)}$$

so it seems that you didn't calculate the degrees of freedom correctly. The fact that the variance is the squared mean in this example does not seem to play a role.

Comment: Thanks. I actually referred to that same page and used degrees of freedom=n because the page said that k referred to the number of $x_i$'s. Why should it be $k=n-1$?

Comment: Because those are the df of the chi-squared distribution and you are using the sample mean and not the population mean in your standard deviation estimator.